# MySQL select distinct with group by unexpectedly slow

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, distinct

I am running a query in the form of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  a.col1,
  b.somecolumn
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.bid = b.id
GROUP BY a.col1, a.col2
```

Table `a` has about 100,000 records and `b` has 100. This runs very slow in, on the order of an hour or more. However, if I change it around a bit, it runs in just a few seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
  SELECT
    a.col1,
    b.somecolumn
  FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.bid = b.id
  GROUP BY a.col1, a.col2
) alias
```

The query is run on a dedicated MySQL instance within a Docker container. Resources are dedicated but limited (1 CPU, 2-4gb RAM).

Will the two forms of query behave the same?

If so, what makes the second so much faster?

What configurations might affect this the most, and why?

Update:
Explain plan for the first query:

```
id    | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows       | extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | SIMPLE      | a          | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 100,000    | Using temporary; Using filesort
2     | SIMPLE      | b          | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 100        | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Second version explain plan:

```
id    | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows       | extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 10,000,000 | Using temporary
2     | DERIVED     | a          | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 100,000    | Using temporary; Using filesort
3     | DERIVED     | b          | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 100        | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Update 2: There are no indexes; However, adding indexes on any combination of `a.bid`, `a.col1`, and `a.col2` yielded no material change to the explanation (other than appearing in the possible_keys field)

Update 3: The server is brought up, the data is loaded into the two tables from an external system, the chosen query is executed, the data is exported to an external system, and the server is brought down. It's started using the following configuration options (no cnf file):

```
--no-defaults
--datadir=./data
--socket=../mysql.sock
--skip-networking
--skip-slave-start
--master_info_repository=TABLE
--performance_schema=OFF
--skip-character-set-client-handshake
--transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED
--group_concat_max_len=18446744073709551615
--default_storage_engine=InnoDB
--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

I cannot change this batch architecture. Each job creates/loads an arbitrary number of tables, and executes an arbitrary number of queries are executed, but for the purposes of this question I have isolated it down to this small case (2 tables, 1 query).

Update 4 (context): My team creates a platform that executes arbitrary SQL provided by our users. I am not a SQL engineer and my role is not to fix SQL. While we can indirectly advise people to change their SQL (i.e. proper `GROUP BY` use), that's not what the question is about.  We are migrating to a new version of our platform that runs most batch jobs significantly faster due to various improvements; A few jobs are 100x slower (like the case in this question). I wish to understand this difference.

TL;DR I can't change the SQL, I want to understand the behavior.

Comment: First things first: `b.somecolumn` needs to be aggregated since it's not mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause. Use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc. MySQL 5.7.4 and older allowed this [wrong] syntax.

Comment: Second, it could be the usage of the right indexes. Post the execution plans.

Comment: @TheImpaler it's running against MySQL 5.6 so it's "valid". While the actual values selected for those columns is indeterminate, it's hard to imagine that being the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: Is the Query cache turned off?  Did you do each timing twice (to avoid other caching)?

Comment: Probably the first thing you need to learn is how to use proper `GROUP BY`.